# Where should development variables go in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to add custom variables to use in Prestashop. In other packages I would throw them in the config file as constants but with Prestashop it looks like it can recreate the settings.inc.php file when upgrading. I don't want to run the risk of losing the vars.

Is there a different spot that I can put them in that wouldn't get tracked in Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Configuration::updateValue('YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME', 'your_value')` to save and update your custom value and `Configuration::get('YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME')` to retrieve it.

These values are stored in the `ps_configuration` table of the PrestaShop database and they will not be overwritten by updates.

Comment: Where would I put these? I don't want to create a module that's not in my repo.

Comment: @kel How do you want to use the stored value?

Comment: They would be used in modules and templates. I'm planning on storing, URI's, API keys, etc that's specific for that install. In other apps like WordPress I've created constants in the wp-config file because I know it wouldn't change. I was planning on doing that with PS, but I noticed that when upgrading it may add/remove things from its config file and I don't want to lose my vars.

Comment: @kel You can insert the values manually in the `ps_configuration` table or run once a custom script that is using `Configuration::updateValue` to store the values, then you can use `Configuration::get` in your modules and templates to retrieve the values.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I'm not wanting to put them in the database manually so I'm creating a module to let me manage them.